# Rename or hide CefSharp.WinForms.dll in C# or VB.NET

Tags: cefsharp

how are you my friends
I apologize for my average english

I'm building a browser that works with Cefsharp, and I have a need and need to rename the library CefSharp.WinForms.dll, even if I have to re-import the library, or include it somewhere far from the application files

Do you have any experiences or thoughts on this idea?
Thank you very much for any suggestion

I am inquiring after I tried to understand how the library works internally, any modification may lead to failure in implementation, so I want a correct and safe way to either rename, re-import, or include the library in a place far from the actual application location